# Bios doesn't see MBR Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, mbr, gpt

I was trying to install steamos as a dual boot but it used to fail because it didn't see windows' free spaces. Someone said convert HDD from GPT to MBR. I did it with gdisk and now my Windows doesn't boot and I can't reinstall it as my bios fails to see my flash drive (it used to see it). I tried Dell ePSA and it sees harddisk without a problem. So does Pardus (a linux distro). I can't find the official recovery cd. When I try to boot, my bios says "NO HDD FOUND". How can I fix this? 
ps. Sorry for bad english. I'm very stressed because of this.

Comment: Thank god! I managed to enter USB disk by switching from UEFI to Legacy from bios. It used to work with UEFI tho. Also I also thank god that my HDD didn't die.

Comment: I managed to install windows in Legacy mode. Now I'm trying to convert HDD to GPT.

Comment: I'm the author of `gdisk`. ***DO NOT*** try to switch back and forth between MBR and GPT as you're doing! Any such switch will completely mess up your boot loaders, causing you disruption. Create one partition scheme and stick with it unless you have a *compelling* reason to change *and you understand the consequences!* As it is, you're blundering around in the dark and will just create more problems for yourself. (Of course, if you're doing this as a learning exercise on a "scrap" computer, fine; but if you rely on your computer for anything, you're just setting yourself up for pain.)

Comment: @Rod I managed to fix it. Was a good learning experience.

Comment: Could you please write down how did you solved the problem as your own answer to this question?